# select statement oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm learning oracle sql from oracle sql fundamentals book, and i found this quiz, the answer as Oracle says 2,3 but they don't work on the sql developers

I know that they have to be like this

> SELECT first_name, last_name, job_id, salary*12 "yearly_sal" FROM employees;
>
> SELECT first_name, last_name, job_id, salary AS "yearly_sal" FROM employees;

but Oracle gives the answer as shown in the image below...

[image]

Comment: SQL Developer, if that is what you mean, is a nice tool for developers and admins, but the only tool you should run the above test in, is called SQLPLUS.

Comment: We teach courses using both SQLPLUS and SQL Developer. Both tools have their uses, there's no 'right' or 'wrong' tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of those answers are correct. Embedded spaces are only valid as column aliases if the alias is delimited by `"`. Also, + cannot be used to concatenate (what I assume to be) strings - instead you can use `||`. They could be corrected as:

1.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, job_id, salary*12 AS "Yearly Sal" FROM employees;
```

2.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, job_id, salary*12 "yearly sal" FROM employees;
```

3.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, job_id, salary AS "yearly sal" FROM employees;
```

4.

```
SELECT first_name || last_name AS name, job_Id, salary*12 "yearly sal" FROM employees;
```

Comment: Everyone makes mistakes from time to time, including me :)

Comment: I'm guessing those aren't spaces but underscores, and they didn't' get printed correctly. Then again, maybe someone made a mistake :)

Comment: That was my first thought, until I saw the underscores that were printed successfully. I figure it was maybe a transcription error.